# Place an IconButton on the top right corner of your scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-scaffold

I want to place an Iconbutton in the top right corner of my Scaffold that programmatically opens a drawer. It should be the top right corner for every displaytype.
Using an appbar would ruin the look of the page since I just need a small icon that shows that a drawer is available. How do I do this the best way?
My Scaffold is a default one.
How can I achieve this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) .
Wrap the body of your Scaffold with a Stack widget and use the [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget as the first child of the stack.

```
GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scafKey = GlobalKey();

 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      key: _scafKey,
      drawer: YourDrawerWidget(),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.short_text),
                  onPressed: (){
                    _scafKey.currentState.openDrawer();
                  })),
          Container(),
       ],
     ),
   ),
 );
}
```

Replace the container with your widget(the original body of the scaffold).

And also the icon of the IconButton to your Icon.

Answer (score 0):

Here the MyHomePage class is the AppBar you need for your Scaffold. All you need to do is change the icon.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: MyHomePage(),
        drawer: Container(
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            AppBarAction(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(60);
}

class AppBarAction extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.print),
      onPressed: () {
        Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your code makes the appbar on the homepage transparent except for the drawer icon? Does that work without using up extra space?